# Preventing devices without a GL extension from downloading app from Google Play

Tags: opengl-es, google-play, android-manifest

Is it possible to make an app unavailable for devices without a specific OpenGL ES extension on Google Play store?

Since `<supports-gl-texture>` takes the extension name, not the texture format, can it be exploited for generic GLES extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe there is, for example:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

This statement will prevent devices that do not support OpenGL es 2.0 from seeing your app in the playstore.

Try this:

```
String extensions = javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10.glGetString(
        GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);
```

According to the docs, the `extensions` variable will contain a space-separated list of supported extensions to GL. So I think you can just use `.contains("GL_OES_depth24");` or something. You're going to have to check some example content of whats returned to see how to check for it.

I don't know how to stop the app from coming up in google play store but you can just put this check at the beginning of your app that will tell users that you can't use this app or something.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this is not what I need. My game has a lot of z-fighting with 16-bit depth buffers (Tegra 2/3), and at the current stage of level design, fixing it would be insanely hard. So I want to hide the game from the devices without `GL_OES_depth24` extension.

Comment: @SiPlus Please see my edit: I don't know if it will help but hopefully it will.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't really want to put this in the engine renderer code because the engine supports 16-bit depth buffer, it's the game levels that look ugly with them. And the game is 500 MB, so a run-time error message is not an option.

Comment: @SiPlus I'm gonna be honest with you. This is beyond the scope of my knowledge, sorry.

Comment: Can you split the download? So users only have to download an initial 10MB or something and run. Then you do your run-time check and only let them download the whole game if they support it.

Comment: @DanWatkins I'm pretty sure you can't split a .apk file into multiple downloads. I think you're supposed to provide two versions of the application, two separate apks.

Comment: I know the 3DMark Ice Storm Benchmark app is 33MB with an additional 173MB download once you run the app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.futuremark.dmandroid.application. So while it isn't necessarily another APK you download, the bulk of the content is downloaded after the initial installation.

Comment: @DanWatkins I get the feeling that the extra installation is being downloaded from another server. So you could put your app on the playstore, then inside the app, put a download link to server somewhere that can download the rest of your app onto the phone in the form of another apk or just data in a directory somewhere.