# Checking for opengl extentions in android manifest

Tags: opengl-es, google-play, android-manifest

I have created an app in unreal engine 4 that is using opengl-es 3.1. The problem is ue4's version of opengl-es also needs support for floating point render target (aka OES_texture_float). I would like to check if the device has the OES_texture_float extension in the android manifest so google play can stop these devices from installing my app.

Following links have helped but I still dont understand what I have to do exacly
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#textures (determining opengl extentions)
[Preventing devices without a GL extension from downloading app from Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261243/preventing-devices-without-a-gl-extension-from-downloading-app-from-google-play)
(question from another user)

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Really surprised that floating point render targets aren't a core part of GLES 3.1 or the Android Extension Pack. Unfortunately, I don't think there's any good way to prevent your app being installed on incompatible devices, so you'll probably just have to catch the problem at runtime and popup a message. One solution would be to require Vulkan, because floating point render targets are part of the Vulkan spec, but you'd be cutting off a disproportionately large proportion of your potential audience that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do think it is possible i think its something like `var extensions = gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS)
bool caninst =extensions.contains(OES_texture_float)` can i do this type of stuff in the manifest file?

Comment: No, I think you can only do extension checks like that at runtime after the user has installed.

Comment: You are probably right. Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Floating point render targets are core features in OpenGL ES 3.2, and most hardware that support 3.1 also support 3.2 (give or take vendor driver updates to actually enable the driver support).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Open GL, but know a little bit about Play Store targeting. The two targeting mechanisms we have in Google Play for distributing Apps to devices based on Open GL are open GL version (which you known about) and [`<supports-gl-texture>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-gl-texture-element).

If `supports-gl-texture` doesn't do what you want, another thing which is a bit more work but should work is to [manually restrict devices in the Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Its suboptimal but will use the restict devices manually function if I see multiple users on the same device type having problems.